# Сослагательное наклонение + уступительные конструкции

Tags: наклонение

Носители языка, требуется Ваше мнение!

Наличие частицы *бы* говорит о сослагательном наклонении. Какое значение оно несёт в уступительных конструкциях: **итеративность** или **ирреальность**?

Например,

С кем бы я ни говорил о моём плане, все меня отговаривали.

За какое бы дело Иван ни брался, у него ничего не получалось.

Comment: "С кем бы я ***ни*** говорил о моём...", вообще-то.

Comment: спасибо исправила

Answer (score 3):

Если убрать в этих примерах частицу "бы", грамматика не нарушается и смысл почти не меняется. Видимо, "бы" добавляет оттенок безнадёжности (относительно желательного исхода) к ситуации из прошлого, экстраполируя её на гипотетические подобные случаи, которых не было. Формальную сослагательность можно усмотреть в том, что если бы персонаж в прошлом предпринял ещё какую-то попытку того же (поговорил бы ещё с кем-то или взялся бы ещё за что-то), то и она закончилась бы тем же.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ но Вы простите пожалуйста потому что я не носитель языка я так и не поняла: какое значение по Вашему мнению здесь сослагательное наклонение имеет...

Comment: В дополнение к основному смыслу фразы - "все, с кем я говорил, меня отговаривали" - частица "бы" косвенно добавляет предположение: "если бы я поговорил ещё с кем-то, он тоже меня отговорил бы" (по форме это сослагательное наклонение).  Без частицы этот дополнительный смысл полностью исчезает.